# Remove Similarities string from list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a need where I need to remove the semantic similarity string from a list of tuples.

Here is my input:

```
[(327, 328, 'Apache'), (327, 329, 'Apache Kafka'), (328, 329, 'Kafka')]
```

Expected output:

```
[(327, 329, 'Apache Kafka')]
```

What is the best way to achieve the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach. Let me know if there is a better way to handle it.

```
data = [(327, 328, 'Apache'), (327, 329, 'Apache Kafka'), (328, 329, 'Kafka')]
uniques = [ i for i in data if not any(i[2].lower() in x[2].lower() and i[2].lower() != x[2].lower() for x in data)]
print(uniques)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way, but maybe not optimal.

```
data = [(327, 328, 'Apache'), (327, 329, 'Apache Kafka'), (328, 329, 'Kafka')]
result = []
print(data)
for item1 in data:
    hasSimilar = False
    for item2 in data:
        if item2==item1:
            continue
        if item1[2] in item2[2]:
            hasSimilar = True
            break
    if not hasSimilar:
        result.append(item1)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[(327, 328, 'Apache'), (327, 329, 'Apache Kafka'), (328, 329, 'Kafka')]
[(327, 329, 'Apache Kafka')]
```

Comment: Brilliant answer.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Please see my approach and let me know if it is the optimal way to do it.

Comment: thotam, I don't know if your approach is optimal but, it is better than mine :) list(set()) is really required ?

Comment: You are right list(set()) is not required. Updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [(327, 328, 'Apache'), (327, 329, 'Apache Kafka'), (328, 329, 'Kafka')]
result = []

for i in data:
    for x in data:
        if i[2] in x[2]:
            if i == x:
                break
            result.append(x)

print(result)
```

Comment: Could you put in some description of how this works so people who are not familiar with the code could follow along?